# VueJS watch отрабатывает дважды

Tags: javascript, vue.js

К примеру есть несколько свойств и вотчер который отслеживает изменение в одном из них, вроде этого

```
Vue.component('Test', {
    props: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: 'one'
        },
        items: {
            type: Array,
            default: function() {
                return [];
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        items: function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log(newVal);
            console.log(oldVal);

            // this.type = 'two';
        }
```

Все хорошо, все работает как надо. Но если в этом вотчере изменить другое свойство вотчер который следит за изменениями в items отработает дважды. 
Т.е. если мы отслеживаем изменение в одном свойстве и пытаемся изменить в нем другое, то отслеживаемый вотчер также отработает с тем что изменили "внутри", как-то так...

```
Vue.component('Test', { 
    props: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: 'one'
        },
        items: {
            type: Array,
            default: function() {
                return [];
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        items: function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log(newVal); // получили вывод в консоли два раза
            console.log(oldVal); // получили вывод в консоли два раза

            this.type = 'two'; // изменили свойство type
        }
```

Почему ? Что я не так делаю ? Как сделать правильно ?